# Select ID & Class Name by jquery Within Multiple Classes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

[How to get id (mymodal , mybtn) and to get Class (close) in span Element in JavaScript. i want to creat a Modal Pop Up Box in CSS & JS. pleas find the atached link that explain the code](https://codepen.io/laith-darwish/pen/gOPKxmb)

```
div class="header" id="hd">
        <div class="overlay">
            <ul class="bxslider">
                <li>
                    <h2>welcome to <span>plus resturent</span></h2>
                    <h3>the best tasting experience</h3>
                    <p>Olive is a Resturant,coffee roastery located on Jordan. 
                     we have awesome recips and the most talented chefs in town!</p>
                    <button class="btn" id="mybtn">creat account</button>
                    <div id="mymodal" class="modal">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <span class="close" id="spn">&times;</span>
                                <h2>modal header</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>kkcmsakfm.sdf</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <h3>dgdsg</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>we sereve quality food</h2>
                    <h3></h3>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>welcome to <span>plus resturent</span></h2>
                    <h3>welcome to slider three</h3>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Would you like to get class of span and `mymodal`, `mybtn` id from span?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for

**how to select a class or id using jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mybtn').click(function() {
   $('#mymodal').show(); 
  })
  $('#mymodal .close').click(() => {
    $('#mymodal').hide();
  })
})
```

note: iam selectiing mybtn id which is unique in current html file, iam also selecting close class with mymodal id so that no other close class will be called(if any exist).
here iam opening a modal and closing it

**below code is with javascript**

```
const mymodal = document.getElementById('mymodal');
const close = document.querySelector('#mymodal .close');
const mybtn = document.getElementById('mybtn');

mybtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  mymodal.style.display = 'inline';
})

close.addEventListener('click', () => {
  mymodal.style.display = 'none';
})
```